# OpenCV2 Stitching Header not found

Tags: c++, opencv, image-stitching

I am trying out the stitching module of openCV2. I am following this example https://code.ros.org/trac/opencv/browser/trunk/opencv/samples/cpp/stitching.cpp?rev=6683

The problem is that, I seem to not find the header "opencv2/stitching/stitcher.hpp"

I also tried searching for this file on my system using "locate" on Ubuntu. But I cannot find the file.

Is it required to install this module? Am I missing something?

Comment: can it be you're running opencv3.0 ? in that case, "opencv2/stitching.hpp"

Comment: no, i cannot find a file by name "*stitching*" on my system

Comment: then, which opencv version are you using ? it definitely [exists in 2.4.9](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/tree/2.4/modules/stitching/include/opencv2/stitching)

Comment: I have 2.3.1. I will update